# OnException does not work for Camel CXF used as Producer

Tags: apache-camel

Camel / CXF versions used:

```
<camel-version>2.18.1</camel-version>
<cxf-version>3.1.7</cxf-version>
```

Using Spring DSL to define routes. Sample code:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint address="{{ws.url}}" id="wsCallCxfBean"
    serviceClass="com.some.package.GeneratedClassEndpoint">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="username" value="${ws.username}" />
        <entry key="password" value="${ws.password}" />
    </cxf:properties>

    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Camel Context:

```
<camel:errorHandler id="deadLetterErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="log:dead" />

<camelContext id="camelCxtId" trace="{{trace}}" handleFault="true" errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <onException id="onCContextException_Common">
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" />
        <!-- mark this as handled -->
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        <to id="onCContextExceptionHandling_Common" pattern="OutOnly" uri="vm:onRouteErrorOutMsgCaught" />
    </onException>
.....
```

Route:

```
<route id="wsCall_RouteID" handleFault="true">
        <description>Call the web service</description>
        <from id="vmFrom_id" uri="vm:fromPOJOVM" />
        <to id="wsCall_id" uri="cxf:bean:wsCallCxfBean" />
                    
        <onException id="onRouteException_WS">
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" />
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <to id="onRouteExceptionHandling_WS" pattern="OutOnly"
                uri="vm:onRouteErrorOutMsgCaught" />
        </onException>
    </route>
```

Issue that I am facing:
**Whenever exception is thrown in CXF, it is not handled by the Camel onException**.
I can see the exception in the log. Sample exception from log (truncated):

```
 WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain:449 - Interceptor for {http://someaddress}WSEndpointService#
{http://someaddress}WSOperation has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:266)
    ...
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)    
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    ...
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
```

I have tried adding handleFault="true" in my camel context and Route - but that did not help.
How can I catch the exception thrown in CXF (for eg: the timeout, unknown host etc) in my camel route?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `<handled><constant>true</constant></handled>` inside your onException definition? [using handled in spring xml dsl](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#_using_handled_with_spring_xml_dsl)

Comment: @PasiÖsterman - Thanks for the reply. I tried using handled, but it did not work :(. I have edited the code samples in the question to reflect this.

Comment: Since you've defined `OnException` in route scope you could also try defining handleFault using route scope as well`<route handleFault="true">`. Alternatively you could try define OnException on your camel context instead of route like [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#_using_handled_with_spring_xml_dsl).

Comment: @PasiÖsterman - I tried both approaches, but still not able to get it working as expected. I have edited the code samples in the question to reflect this